# Are class hierarchies on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Are questions on simple class hierarchies, like this [recent one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125726/review-my-class-hierarchy), on topic? I think they are perfectly on topic here, but also that they might find a much better home at [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). As @YamMarcovic notes in a comment to the question, a class diagram is essentially code. Initially I agreed, but now I'm a little bit undecided.

Code Review SE is still in it's early days, and unfortunately they still haven't decided if class hierarchies are on topic there, as the [relevant meta discussion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74/should-design-questions-be-on-topic-here) is still open. Their faq [specifically disqualifies questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) on "Higher-level architecture and design of software systems", and a [meta question on those](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213/where-do-high-level-architecture-and-design-questions-go) points to Programmers as the appropriate site. But can we really classify a simple class hierarchy question as a "Higher-level architecture and design of software systems" question?

If we decide that they are off topic here, should we care that they might not find a better home at Code Review?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like DKnight, I think this type of question is too localized to be a fit here.

For this to be on-topic here, it'd have to be asking about something far more general or high-level: "I'm working on this UML diagram, and I'm not sure whether I should do X or Y. Which way is better if I want to demonstrate Z?".

Posting a picture of a UML diagram and asking for critiques is way too specific and unlikely to help other people in the future, and I would say in general code/diagram critiques are off-topic.

Code Review.SE is currently unique on the network in its focus on helping people with very localized, non-generalizable problems like this: I'm not totally convinced it's on-topic there, but I can definitely see why people would think that.

I've reached out to the moderators on Code Review to look at this question and provide their thoughts, but it's the weekend and they haven't responded yet.

Comment: I was about to ask if the Code Review mods responded, when I noticed your comment on the question... "too localized" here, "off topic" on Code Review was exactly what I thought of the question. It will take a quite better question than the one we're discussing to get a clear idea if the type is on topic or not, if one actually comes along. Accepted the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Who else is this question going to help?

Seems too focused a question to be on topic here.  There are some good answers but they don't work if you rewrite the question to be more general.  It would be nice if this works on code review and could be moved but no matter what, it doesn't belong here.  Voted to close.

General questions on the subject should be fine, these validate my homework answers don't meet the faq requirements.